# How to load grid from xml

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid. I want to load data from xml. How to define store.

My grid code is :

```
{
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    id: 'COGRID,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
                    frame: true,
                    columns : this.columns,
                    store :  ?? // How to define grid
                    stripeRows: true,


                }
```

My XML :

```
<R>
<Headers>
<Header>VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="130"  DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="STU" RESIZE="false"  DOMAIN="">ABC</HEADER>
<Header>VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="130"  DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="STU" RESIZE="false"  DOMAIN="">EFG</HEADER>
<Header>VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="130"  DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="STU" RESIZE="false"  DOMAIN="">HIJ</HEADER>
<DATA>
 <G STU="PCA" SUB="ffa" EXL="Yes" />
    <G STU="PCB" SUB="ffb" EXL="No" />
    <G STU="PCC" SUB="ffc" EXL="Yes" />
    <G STU="PCD" SUB="ffd" EXL="No" />
</DATA>
<R>
```

Now here my data is column data and header is grid column. Any help will help me a lot. Thanks.